How to print the GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE (GOT) of the current process in memory
How can I print the content of the memory mapped .got section for the current process?
I don't want to parse the elf binary file.
I want my application to know the .got of its own process (as it changes over time).

ELF and all ELF-related information is only in the file, not in memory.

And what is the underlying and actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need to get the .got table? How will that solve your actual problem?

Not every ELF section is loaded into the memory when the process is running, and not "as is". This is in general. But your specific problem might have other solutions.

The ELF format is something that is consumed by the loader to lay out your program in the memory, and not something that is being just copied into your process space.

the .got section is used extensively by the dynamic linker. As my binary is linked dynamically it must have it mapped to memory.

I want to do patch different things in the binary and I want to see the result of the dynamic linker in the GOT at runtime.

So your question should ask how you access the global offsets table of the process from within the process itself, not related to ELF whatsoever (perhaps can be added as reference). Not saying it is easy or possible at all, but the question could use an improvement. I'd think GOT belongs to the linker/loader process and not to the loaded process.
